# Magento 2.2.5 After Upgrade To 2.3 CLI commands don't work

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, upgrade, cli

I upgraded magento version by documentation, after upgrade this happens:

When running **php bin/magento cache:flush** or any other bin/magento command error appears
 **There are no commands defined in the " " namespace**
When running **php bin/magento list** these errors appear:

```
In ServiceManager.php line 1130:

An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentosetupconsolecommanddbstatuscommand(alias: Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DbStatusCommand).  


In ServiceManager.php line 941:

An exception was raised while creating "Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DbStatusCommand"; no instance returned  


In ClassReader.php line 19:

Class Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\FileSystem\XmlReader does not exist
```

There are no missing module.xml in any custom modules.
UPDATE:

few modules module.xml had this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
```

instead it should be this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
```

UPDATE2: same error still persists. 
Tried

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/*
```

and **composer update**  above fix didn not help still.

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue did someone able to resolve this issue?

Comment: var/generation/ no longer exists. you should delete "generated" in you magento-root

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error some times ago. Generally these errors occur because of missing of `module.xml` of any custom modules please check whether there is any `module.xml` is missing or not of your custom modules.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: @Trenox if my answer is helpful and resolve your issue then mark my answer correct and upvote my answer so it helps others as well. keep coding :) thanks :)

Comment: Yes seems like there was a problem with xsi schema location declaration in couple module.xml

Comment: Edited question again. Problem still persists.

Comment: @Trenox check whether any of your custom module  `module.xml` is missing or not you can check it by going your every custom module path `[Vendor]/[custommodulename]/etc/module.xml`. You don't need to change any `module.xml` of your custom module. I emphasize on `missing` word.

Comment: None are missing.